# Difference in lightning network node/channel stats between my LND, what's shown in amboss and 1ml.com

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, statistics

When I run `./lncli getnetworkinfo` I get the following:

```
{
    "graph_diameter": 13,
    "avg_out_degree": 5.67523205795789,
    "max_out_degree": 117,
    "num_nodes": 17668,
    "num_channels": 50135,
    "total_network_capacity": "135922147300", // 1359 BTC
    "avg_channel_size": 2711122.914131844,
    "min_channel_size": "1050",
    "max_channel_size": "500000000",
    "median_channel_size_sat": "1000000",
    "num_zombie_chans": "19"
}
```

Amboss shows the stats as follows:

[image]

While 1ml shows as follows:

[image]

**Node count:**

- My LND: 17,668
- Amboss: 16,671
- 1ML: 17,780

**Channel count:**

- My LND: 50,135
- Amboss: 84,215
- 1ML: 86,747

**Network capacity:**

- My LND: 1,359 BTC
- Amboss: 4,591 BTC
- 1ML: 4,548 BTC

For channel capacity and network capacity, there is a huge different between what my LND is showing and what amboss/1ml is showing. Should I do something (like connect with more diverse set of peers or force crawling again) to get my LND stats up to date?